# Blueimp file upload validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload

I'm using [jQuery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for file upload. Uploading works fine. But now I want to add any restrictions for file size and type. Unfortunately, validation doesn't fired.

I include next plugin files: jquery.fileupload.js, jquery.fileupload-ui.js, jquery.fileupload-validation.js,
jquery.fileupload-process.js

My code

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: uploadUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    dropZone: $("#dropzone"),
    maxFileSize: 10000000,
    maxNumberOfFiles: 5,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(csv|zip|xlsx?|ods)$/i,
    singleFileUploads: true, //upload files one by one
    autoSubmit: false,
    add: function (e, data) { 
        //code
        data.submit();
    }
});
```

But I'm successfull in txt files loading (or any other file).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this part :

```
add: function (e, data) { 
    //code
    data.submit();
}
```

Because data.submit() is fired to send file (so after validate)

Comment: not working, beacuse then nothing will be uploaded any more